# Drupal 7 - assigning custom class to nested menu UL elements

Tags: drupal, menu

I'm trying to theme my menu to alter the default UL classes. So far I'm working with the following function:

```
function theme_menu_tree($variables){
  return '<ul class="my-class">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

This works great but I need to apply a different class to the UL inside a parent item. Right now I get

```
<ul class="my-class">
  <li class="dropdown">Item
    <ul class="my-class">
      <li>Link1</li>
      <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I target the second UL to give it a different class using the theme_menu_tree function?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to override the menu class? Why not look at the CSS id or class of the body, section, or block that the menu is in and use that of where you are at and use that to override it?

For example, I'm using this to override the default appearance of a leaf menu item in a block:

```
#block-menu-menu-top-navigation ul li.leaf
{
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, there is no such thing as *default UL classes*. There are theme functions (recognizable by the function name starting with *theme_*) and templates (recognizable by the filename ending with *.tpl.php*). Neither makes *any* assumptions about what HTML elements are used to render the data. Especially, Drupal makes no assumptions about which classes should be applied to the elements that a template or theme function produces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [Menu attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. It lets you define CSS class and ID.